# Python - Cell type 'NoneType' while value inside. How to transform that?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have been struggling with this for the last couple of hours. I am writing a script for a one-time usage that I hope will save me a lot of time. 
The purpose of the script is as follow:

```
#In a certain directory, loop through all the .xlsx files
#From each .xlsx file, select a whole column based on the column header (user input) (in this case, a year)
#Copy these columns successively into a new workbook.
```

I have beforehand transformed  .tsv files into a .xlsx files using pandas as follow:

```
# Read tsvfile into dataframe in using panda
df = pandas.read_table(tsvfile)
# New excelfile
writer = ExcelWriter(tsvfile + '.xlsx')
# Write dataframe to excel
df.to_excel(writer, header = True)
writer.save()
```

This worked perfectly, and I now have multiple .xlsx files that can be opened with no change in the data. The issue is that according to excel, the cell values have been saved in textformat. When trying to use the content of these cells in my python script, I often get the following error message:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute ‘……’
```

The strange thing is, that I am able to put these cells into a list, and I can read the value from the cells that way:

```
[… '2005 ', '2006 ', '2007 ', '2008 ', '2009 ', '2010 ', '2011 ', '2012 ', '2013 ', '2014 '….]
```

But I still cannot match it with '2015'. I also cannot delete the spaces after each year, because the type is still 'NoneType'.

This is the function I use to find the column number (the one with the list):

```
def checkvalue(x, y, z):
"""Check if userinput (y) can be found in the row (z), return column number if found"""
print(z)
values = []
for j, cells in enumerate(range(1, x.max_column + 1), 1):
   #Cursor
    cursor = x.cell(row = z, column = cells)
    values.append(cursor.value)

if y in values:
    return y
else:
    return 999999
```

I have uploaded one dataset as example (it is data from Eurostat): https://ufile.io/fut70

My whole script (incomplete, work in progress): https://pastebin.com/tdmEynUm

What I’d like to know is, what can I do to either circumvent this ‘NoneType’ issue? Should I rewrite the entire row within the script? Or should I check whether I can do something with panda? If I use `y = 2015` (with a space at the end), then I can find the column. But I can't assume that all my excel files have that extra space at the end 100% of the time...
I am lost.
I realize this is probably a very specific issue so I hope I have provided enough information.

Many thanks for your time

Comment: I am little lost, but could you try.  `df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()` after you pd.read_table  statement.

Comment: This worked, thank you. As usual, the simplest solutions are often the best.
If someone else has interest in researching how it is possible to have a variable that is NoneType while it has a value inside, or how to fix that, I'm also interested!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are reading in columns with whitespaces from your excel file.   Let's eliminate that white space using:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
```